# Does ubuntu 17.10 support the AMD Ryzen APUs?

Tags: 17.10, amd-processor, support

The new AMD APUs have published.

[AMD Ryzen Desktop APUs](https://www.amd.com/en-us/press-releases/Pages/first-amd-ryzen-2018feb12.aspx)

Before building the systems,

I'm worried about installing Ubuntu 17.10 on them.

Does ubuntu 17.10 support the AMD Ryzen APUs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try 18.04 but it seems [they are now supported](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=ryzen-linux-10way&num=1)

Answer (score 0):

No, but you can try installing unstable kernel and drivers.

Look here: [What is needed to use Raven Ridge Ryzen 5 2400G?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1007350/what-is-needed-to-use-raven-ridge-ryzen-5-2400g)