# HOW TO FIX drm:amdgpu_job_timedout [amdgpu]] *ERROR* ring gfx timeout ? ON MY RYZEN 5 2400G APU

Tags: amdgpu

My PC freezes randomly without any workload. only ALTSyS REISUB works. I installed fresh ubuntu 18.04.2 on my system and this is the only OS installed in my pc. I dont have any other Graphics Card And It only uses the GPU integrated with the Ryzen5 2400G APU. 
In the log I find this:

```
14:13:28 kernel: **[drm:amdgpu_job_timedout [amdgpu]] *ERROR*** ring gfx timeout, last signaled seq=8349, last emitted seq=8351
14:13:18 kernel: amdgpu 0000:06:00.0: VM_L2_PROTECTION_FAULT_STATUS:0x00000000
14:07:31 pulseaudio: [pulseaudio] bluez5-util.c: GetManagedObjects() failed: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.TimedOut: Failed to activate service 'org.bluez': timed out (service_start_timeout=25000ms)
14:07:18 spice-vdagent: Cannot access vdagent virtio channel /dev/virtio-ports/com.redhat.spice.0
14:07:11 wpa_supplicant: bgscan simple: Failed to enable signal strength monitoring
14:07:08 NetworkManager: <error> [1551343028.4130] wifi-wext: (wlx503eaa693cdb): error setting powersave 1
14:07:06 spice-vdagent: Cannot access vdagent virtio channel /dev/virtio-ports/com.redhat.spice.0
14:07:06 wpa_supplicant: dbus: Failed to construct signal
14:06:49 kernel: kfd kfd: kgd2kfd_probe failed
14:06:49 kernel: AMD-Vi: Unable to write to IOMMU perf counter.
14:06:49 kernel: ***ACPI BIOS Error (bug)***: Failure creating [\_SB.SMIB], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20180531/dsfield-594)
```

**What is "ACPI BIOS Error (bug)"?**, and what is **amdgpu_job_timedout [amdgpu]] *ERROR*** ring gfx timeout**
How can I solve the problem?
What information you need to properly understand the problem? [Log image url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CZU8s.png)

Answer (score 1):

In this post they're talking about the same problem as you. [Ryzen-5-2400G-Ubuntu-What-is-needed-to-use](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1007350/what-is-needed-to-use-raven-ridge-ryzen-5-2400g)
As far as I know you need to **install the drivers from external way**, i think **in that post you will find the help** you need.
I Hope i help you. Regards

Comment: I'm using kernel 4.18.0, and I still get freezes with the amdgpu_job_timedout message in the logs. And it seems that AMD still has Ryzen 5 2400G official drivers only for Windows, not Linux.