# "Failed to start Load/Save Screen Backlight Brightness of backlight:acpl_video0" error

Tags: boot, 18.04

While booting up Ubuntu 18.04, I got the error of

```
Failed to start Load/Save Screen Backlight Brightness of backlight:acpl_video0
```

and after the normal loading screen turned into a terminal looking thing. It proceeded to give me several

```
failed to write reg
```

errors and then the errors

```
[drm:amdgpu_job_timeout [amdgpu]] *ERROR* ring gfx timeout, signaled seq=1, emitted seq=5
```

and

```
[drm:amdgpu_job_timeout [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Process information: process pid 0 thread pid 0
```

What are these, and how can I get Ubuntu to boot? I tried booting in safeboot, and it booted fine, but when I tried to reboot it got stuck at the loading image.

Comment: Do you have a Ryzen computer?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs Yes, I do. Amd GPU and CPU.

Answer (score 0):

Based on comments please refer to this Q&A:

- [What is needed to use Raven Ridge Ryzen 5 2400G?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1007350/what-is-needed-to-use-raven-ridge-ryzen-5-2400g)

Notably:

> It seems the latest fixes from AMD finally resolved all my issues. See
>   https://cgit.freedesktop.org/~agd5f/linux/log/?h=amd-staging-drm-next
>   For now you need to compile your own kernel or wait till those fixes
>   land in your distribution.

Source: [HOW TO FIX drm:amdgpu_job_timedout [amdgpu]] *ERROR* ring gfx timeout ? ON MY RYZEN 5 2400G APU](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1121921/how-to-fix-drmamdgpu-job-timedout-amdgpu-error-ring-gfx-timeout-on-my-ry)

Comment: How am I supposed to use the freedesktop link?