# Screen Tear in 19.04 on Ryzen 5 2400G

Tags: drivers, 19.04, tearing, amd-ryzen

My new PC with Ubuntu 19.04, and a AMD [Ryzen 5 2400G CPU with Radeon Vega RX 11](https://www.amd.com/en/products/apu/amd-ryzen-5-2400g) graphics, shows screen tear on YouTube videos and in gaming, is this because of Linux ? I've looked around and more people seem to get this on Linux than windows.

I've tried finding the drivers for my APU and its only available on windows

Comment: You can see this thread https://askubuntu.com/questions/1007350/what-is-needed-to-use-raven-ridge-ryzen-5-2400g

Comment: I've added my ubuntu version

Comment: I had that bad on similar hardware, but that is now gone. I am using kernel 5.3.0-050300rc6-generic

Answer (score 5):

Solution for AMDGPU

Create folder xorg.conf.d using

```
sudo mkdir /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d
```

Create a new configuration file using

```
sudo nano /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-amdgpu.conf
```

and add

```
Section "Device"
        Identifier "AMD"
        Driver  "amdgpu"
        Option "TearFree" "true"
EndSection
```

Reference: [How to Fix AMD GPU Radeon Screen Tearing in Debian, Linux Mint and Ubuntu - YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WWg8q_f7nI4)

Comment: Unfortunately, if I do so the graphic server won't load on boot. I had to boot linux "text-only" and remove the code. I have a ryzen 5 2400GE. Any idea on why it does not work?

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me on a similar Ryzen GPU and Linux Mint. Can anyone explain it?